# Null pointer exception while execution a jdbc code in net beans?

Tags: java, jdbc, nullpointerexception

i m connecting ms access to odbc and odbc to javacode.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author aditya
 */
public class Odbc {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con=null;Statement st=null;

        try {
          Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
System.out.println("driver loaded");           

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
System.out.println(ex);           
        }
        try {
           con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:studentdsn");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Odbc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            Statement St = con.createStatement();
            String sql="insert into Student values(111,gfhgf,kjhk,123,jgfj)";  
 int n; 
 n=st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

here.. i m getting runtime error. deferencing null pointer.

```
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }


    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two Statement type variables. One which you defined as null:

```
Statement st=null;
```

and one which was actually initialized ("s" is uppercase here):

```
Statement St = con.createStatement();
```

then you are calling a function on the null variable:

```
n=st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `con` as null and then you try to initialize it like:

```
try {
       con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:studentdsn");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Odbc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Now if you get exception while creating connection, your connection would still be null and then you try to use null connection to create statement as below:

```
try {
   Statement St = con.createStatement();
```

And hence null pointer exception.

Create all the JDBC connection related statement in one try catch block and most importantly find out why connection creation failed.